# python configuration on windows

Tags: python, windows, configuration

When I execute this script from the command line on Windows:

```
MyProgram.py %*
```

MyProgram.py is launched with python, but not the arguments. How to solve this ?

Edit : However the following batch file:

```
python.exe MyProgram.py %*
```

works fine.

Comment: If you `import sys` and do `print(sys.argv)` in your script what gets returned?

Comment: And if you execute it like this: `python.exe MyProgram.py %*`?

Comment: to arbulgazar: yes this works but my python program executes some other batch files which are calling other python programs in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! In the registry, I looked for the entry named "py_auto_file" and changed the subkey

```
shell/open/command
```

default value from

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1"
```

to

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, normally you just have to write it like this:

```
python MyProgram.py arg1 arg2
```

That will pass in two arguments to **MyProgram.py** that you can get access to using sys.argv. If you want more control, then you should take a look at Python argparse (or optparse if you're running an older version).

Comment: when I write "python MyProgram.py arg1 arg2" it's ok. But when I write "MyProgram.py arg1 arg2", the args aren't passed.

Comment: After doing a bit more digging, it sounds like you may have to call python first unless you turn your script into an executable.